# Slow when reading from MongoDB using PHP mongodb driver with replica set

Tags: php, mongodb

So when I connect to a MongoDB with multiple hosts, there is a delay in every one minute when executing a command. The delay time is exactly 10 seconds. I know this sounds so weird.

First I thought that the problem is related to MongoDB server configuration. But it only happens when I use PHP mongodb driver because it works fine when I tested with Java mongodb driver.
- MongoDB Server: 3.6
- PHP mongodb driver: 1.5.3
- Java mongodb driver: 3.10.1

I also tested older version of PHP mongodb driver with the same problem.

PHP

```php
// start tracking reading time
$start = microtime(true);

$m = new \MongoDB\Client('mongodb://rs1.host.com,rs2.host.com');
$db = $m->selectDatabase('test');
// slow when querying
$db->selectCollection('user')->findOne();

// end tracking reading time
$end = microtime(true);
$duration = $end - $start;
```

Full source code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r-EKiCntZbUq59sFzaBOiCrfy0tzjadt

Java

```java
Date date1 = new Date();
long start = date1.getTime();

MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://rs1.host.com,rs2.host.com");
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("ple");

db.getCollection("user").find().first();

Date date2 = new Date();
long end = date2.getTime();

System.out.println((end - start) + "ms");
```

Full source code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TYTFrRxUiQUZdIUJdetllHpnOYHQiepd

I repeated the script above every 2 seconds, so here is result I tested:

PHP

```
0.013s
0.0056s
0.0135s
0.0052s
10.0271s (54sec from last delay)
0.0057s
0.0059s
0.0122s
0.0108s
0.0106s
0.0133s
0.014s
0.0095s
0.0076s
0.0145s
0.0102s
0.0148s
0.0058s
0.0132s
0.0125s
0.0134s
0.0056s
0.0055s
0.0135s
0.0124s
0.0116s
0.013s
0.013s
0.0139s
0.0135s
0.0132s
10.0234s (52sec from last delay)
0.0125s
0.0128s
0.0168s
0.0121s
0.0131s
0.0134s
0.0141s
0.0128s
0.0128s
0.0123s
0.0131s
0.0156s
0.006s
0.0053s
0.0058s
0.0136s
0.0131s
0.0139s
0.0131s
0.0063s
0.0125s
0.0127s
0.013s
0.0061s
0.0058s
10.015s (52sec from last delay)
0.0071s
0.0144s
```

Java

```
16ms
17ms
17ms
16ms
19ms
17ms
16ms
17ms
16ms
17ms
17ms
16ms
17ms
16ms
16ms
16ms
16ms
17ms
16ms
15ms
17ms
17ms
15ms
17ms
16ms
17ms
16ms
15ms
16ms
17ms
15ms
17ms
16ms
16ms
14ms
18ms
16ms
15ms
17ms
16ms
15ms
17ms
17ms
16ms
16ms
17ms
16ms
20ms
16ms
16ms
19ms
15ms
15ms
17ms
16ms
16ms
16ms
15ms
15ms
17ms
16ms
17ms
16ms
15ms
16ms
18ms
15ms
17ms
18ms
15ms
15ms
17ms
16ms
16ms
16ms
15ms
16ms
16ms
17ms
16ms
17ms
17ms
15ms
16ms
16ms
14ms
16ms
17ms
16ms
15ms
17ms
17ms
15ms
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with PHP mongodb driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced exactly the same situation and in our case, it was because the PHP client couldn't reach the arbitrer, even though we didn't mention it anywhere.
By opening the firewall on the arbitrer to our client, we solved the situation.

Comment: You're right. In our case, PHP client couldn't connect to the Arbiter because it wasn't running. By the way, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You just save me, I was facing the exactly same situation <3

Comment: You saved my day! Do you remember how you figured this out? Was it logged anywhere (eg.: connection timeout)?